# Are achievements account or character bound?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Do different characters across the same account share achievements? Is it possible to work towards one achievement on multiple accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official GW2 wiki page on achievements](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Achievement),

> Achievements are shared between characters on the account, meaning that you can (and sometimes must) use multiple characters to finish certain achievements or achievement categories.

Comment: This is often very convenient for the daily achievements. Sometimes that kill variety can be a pain, but jumping on an alt in a different part of the world makes it much easier.

Comment: Re. the kill variety achievement, 'neutral' animals like rabbits or raccoons also count towards it.  Helps a huge deal.